# Android http requests

Tags: android, json, http

I am doing HTTP json request from activity at higher rate that is around 600 request which reply with json response
this takes a lot of time sometimes app become non responding what should i do so as to optimize it.
if it run properly it takes long time please let me have some solution

Comment: We need more information than that - please post example code, what you have tried or a specific algo that you have difficulty implementing.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to run the process in the background. This way your UI will not freeze.

And also read this link: [Making ListView Scrolling Smooth](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html)

Comment: Async task will not make it fast and utill that request are not completed i cant move forward so that has to be done first

Comment: Is there a way were i can perform simultaneous http request